# Streaming: VM freezes for large file

Tags: stream, erlang, elixir, streaming, beam

I am building a pipeline to process, aggregate and transform data from csv files, then write back to another csv file… I load rows from a 19 column csv file, and with some mathematical operations (map reduce style) write back 30 columns in another csv.

And it was going fine until I tried to upload a 25mb file to the application, 250000 rows, and then I decided to stream all the operations instead of eagerly processing… but now that I’m changing function by function with streams, I faced a problem that I don’t understand why, after only 5 fields created, when I try to write to file the program just freezes and stops writing after a few thousand lines.
[image: Frozen writing process after thousands of lines been written]
I’m streaming every single function so it shouldn’t have any locks as far as I understand, and for the first thousands writes it works fine so I wonder what’s happening, in the erlang observer I can only see usage of resources dropped to near 0 and it doesn’t write to the file anymore.

This is my stream function (before I just load from file), and next is my write function:

```
def process(stream, field_longs_lats, team_settings) do
    main_stream =
      stream
      # Removing once that don't have timestamp
      |> Stream.filter(fn [time | _tl] -> time != "-" end)
      # Filter all duplicated rows by timestamp
      |> Stream.uniq_by(fn [time | _tl] -> time end)
      |> Stream.map(&Transform.apply_row_tranformations/1)

    cumulative_milli =
      main_stream
      |> Stream.map(fn [_time, milli | _tl] -> milli end)
      |> Statistics.cumulative_sum()

    speeds =
      main_stream
      |> Stream.map(fn [_time, _milli, _lat, _long, pace | _tl] ->
        pace
      end)
      |> Stream.map(&Statistics.get_speed/1)

    cals = Motion.calories_per_timestep(cumulative_milli, cumulative_milli)

    long_stream =
      main_stream
      |> Stream.map(fn [_time, _milli, lat | _tl] -> lat end)

    lat_stream =
      main_stream
      |> Stream.map(fn [_time, _milli, _lat, long | _tl] -> long end)

    x_y_tuples =
      RelativeCoordinates.relative_coordinates(long_stream, lat_stream, field_longs_lats)

    x = Stream.map(x_y_tuples, fn {x, _y} -> x end)
    y = Stream.map(x_y_tuples, fn {_x, y} -> y end)

    [x, y, cals, long_stream, lat_stream]
  end
```

write:

```
def write_to_file(keyword_list, file_name) do
    file = File.open!(file_name, [:write, :utf8])

    IO.write(file, V4.empty_v4_headers() <> "\n")

    keyword_list
    |> Stream.zip()
    |> Stream.each(&write_tuple_row(&1, file))
    |> Stream.run()

    File.close(file)
  end

@spec write_tuple_row(tuple(), pid()) :: :ok
  def write_tuple_row(tuple, file) do
    IO.inspect("writing #{inspect(tuple)}")

    row_content =
      Tuple.to_list(tuple)
      |> Enum.map_join(",", fn value -> Transformations.to_string(value) end)

    IO.write(file, row_content <> "\n")
  end
```

Comment: It might be time to move from `Stream` to `Flow` https://hexdocs.pm/flow/Flow.html or even `Broadway`  https://hexdocs.pm/broadway/Broadway.html#full-list so that you can control the buffer sizes of you intermediate processing.

Comment: My plan is to use flow in the end indeed, and I already tried to use in this code but start getting some IO errors, but I think it should work even if slower this way, and I really would like to know what's going in this case so maybe I can prevent on future iterations

Comment: your code is quite complex - best to try testing functions individually as possible in order to identify what  is the root cause.  You've got the data so its your shot really.